# query wordpress posts by polylang language on MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, polylang

I'm trying to build a MySQL query to select last post by language (Polylang plugin) but I can't find what table and field does Polylang store the language of each post.
Any clue?

Comment: I think the information about the mapping is stored in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table. Its an array with your locales and the post id. ``SELECT * FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` WHERE `taxonomy` = 'post_translations'``

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Is there any info available about the codes Polylang uses when building the wp_term_taxonomy.description field values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's too late to answer your question, but I gonna write it, for future users.

you can find everything related to `Polylang` in `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy` tables.

for example, if I want to get the language of a specific post with id = `157896`.

In the `wp_term_relationships` in `object_id` column I should search for `157896` and I will get

```
object_id | term_taxonomy_id
----------------------------
  157896  |     26284
  157896  |     26130
  157896  |      11
```

and in `wp_term_taxonomy` we have:

```
term_taxonomy_id | taxonomy | description
---------------------------------------------
26284 | post_translations | a:2:{s:2:"en";i:157896;s:2:"de";i:157894;}
26130 | category | Description ... ...
11    | language | a:3:{s:6:"locale";s:5:"en_UK";s:3:"rtl";i:0;s:9:"flag_code";s:2:"en";}
```

`26130` is related to the category

`26280` means this post translated in `de` and `en` languages and the post number for `en` is `157896` and the post number for `de` is `157894`

`11` means the post with `id = 157896` is in `en`(English) language.

`wp_term_relationships` is a `pivot` table.

Answer (score 8):

The following mysql query will find all published wordpress posts which is in en language of polylang plugin:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND ID IN (
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '"en";i:', -1), ';',1) FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` WHERE `taxonomy` = 'post_translations' ) order by ID desc
```

Comment: Seriously helpfull!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more.